# Using Auth::user(); in core php

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm working on a project , the problem is that some part of the project is made in laravel and some part in core php . Now i want to perform authentication through Auth Facade for my project . Some files are being accessed through routes and some files which are in core php are being accessed directly . so the files which are being accessed through routes Auth is working perfect But what to do for core php files , i don't want to use **$_SESSION**. Please suggest me a way to use Auth in my core php files.

Comment: Can you make use of the `auto loader` from your vendor and import the `Auth` functionality?

Comment: i did'nt get can you explain please !

Comment: This sounds like a pretty nasty setup.  Why do you have the mix, out of interest.

Comment: @JohnHalsey I am not sure as well why use core php and a framework. But it is a good acceptable setup to mix frameworks when such is justifiable (I.e:. Use wordpress for content management but use symfony to manage the products and payments of an application). Though for his scenario I am at a lost as well. Could be purely out of curiosity

Comment: @utmsandeep which of the wording is not understandable by you so I can try and explain?

Comment: @DiogoSanto Yes agreed, I've heard of such things like that.  But php core mixed with Laravel seems pointless.

Comment: @JohnHalsey that it does, I am just thinking it must be a personal project. You know, "in the name of science" kind of thing :3

Comment: actually this is an old project developed by other developers. i don't know why they mixed these things.

Comment: now my boss order me to fix it's authentication system without losing much time.

Comment: @DiogoSanto how can  we import  Auth facade . please  can you show me something regarding this. I just started working 15 days ago on laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You can include autoload.php in your core files and then you can try to get laravel functions as we do in WordPress codex.

Comment: yes , i am talking about autoload.php, Had you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

In your Laravel application:

Generate a session token and store it in the Laravel session:

```
// Generate a session token
$sessionToken = generateSessionToken();

// Store the session token in the Laravel session
session(['session_token' => $sessionToken]);
```

Pass the session token to your core PHP files (e.g., via a shared storage like a database):

```
// Pass the session token to core PHP files
$sharedStorage->storeSessionToken($sessionToken);
```

In your core PHP files:

Retrieve the session token from the shared storage:

```
// Retrieve the session token from the shared storage
$sessionToken = $sharedStorage->getSessionToken();
```

Authenticate the user in your core PHP files using the Laravel session:

```
// Include the Laravel autoload.php file
require_once '/path/to/laravel/autoload.php';

// Start a Laravel session
session_start();

// Retrieve the session data using the session token
$sessionData = getSessionData($sessionToken);

// Check if the user is authenticated
if ($sessionData && $sessionData['user_id']) {
    // User is authenticated
    $userId = $sessionData['user_id'];
} else {
    // User is not authenticated
  
}
```